# Using https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp with a cmake build

Tags: c++, cmake, mqtt, pahocpp

I'm a bit new to `CMake`. So this might be a noob question..

I'm trying to build cpp project with `CMake`. I would like my program to publish to a mqtt broker. I'm running on Linux.

So I installed `https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp` and the corresponding c project by doing (side by side)

```
$ git clone https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c.git
$ cd paho.mqtt.c
$ git checkout v1.3.1

$ cmake -Bbuild -H. -DPAHO_WITH_SSL=ON -DPAHO_ENABLE_TESTING=OFF
$ sudo cmake --build build/ --target install
$ sudo ldconfig
```

as per the documentation and then doing.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ../
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

which all worked fine without any errors..
Now what do i put in my own cmakelists file in my own project that I can use the libraries?
So I can do.

```
#include "mqtt/async_client.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
   mqtt::async_client cli(DFLT_ADDRESS, "", 120, PERSIST_DIR);


   return 0;
}
```

I tried a simple.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project (hello)

find_package(PahoMqttCpp REQUIRED)


add_executable(hello helloworld.cpp)
target_link_libraries(hello ${PAHO_CPP_LIB})
```

But that does not seem to be enough.. 
I get

```
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0xd3): undefined reference to `mqtt::async_client::~async_client()'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55800526/3987854). You shouldn't link using `${PAHO_CPP_LIB}`, but instead use `PahoMqttCpp::PahoMqttCpp`.

Comment: unfortunately as the issue shows it does not seem to work i tried target_link_libraries(hello ${PAHO_CPP_LIB} paho-mqttpp3)
which got me over a hump but now stuck on undefined reference to symbol 'MQTTProperties_free'

Answer (score 5):

Okay, after some digging, I found the correct thing to write is:

```
target_link_libraries(hello paho-mqttpp3 paho-mqtt3as)
```

Comment: Hi. Would you be available to give me some insight on how to build (and, hopefully, how to use) the paho-mqtt lib in C++? You see, I've never wrote code in C++, the closest language I know being C, and I haven't been much successful adding the paho-mqtt lib to a project, yet. My personal e-mail is pedroalvesvalentim@gmail.com . Any help would be much appreciated.