# Configure cmake for MQTT

Tags: c++, cmake, raspberry-pi, mqtt, paho

I`m fairly new to C++ and I trying to set up a MQTT client on a Raspberry pi.
Therover I am using the https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp repo.

I have cloned the repo and ran the following command:
`./install_paho_mqtt_c.sh`

If I read correct this should build the code of the library.
Now I want to use the library in the code, but how do I edit the cmake file so it takes in account the library?

I`m using Clion and a full remote host compiler, see the figure for the project tree on the raspberry pi.

In the folder tmp the main.cpp file is located.

[image: project tree]

The folder paho.mqtt.cpp is the cloned github repo.

In the next photo is the simple cmake file.

[image: cmake file]

Is there someone out here who could help me out with getting the `paho.mqtt.cpp` library include in the project. And may be an example for setting up a MQTT client.

Comment: Please do not post images of text, post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it as code. Images are hard to read and impossible for people that need to use screen readers.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55800526/1548468). Not sure why the answer was not accepted.

Comment: @Botje Because it doesn't work.

Comment: Fair enough, but please ask a new question or comment there instead of replying to a two-year old comment.

Comment: @Botje Sorry, the second half of my comment was cut off. The answer you linked to doesn't work at all, but the answer by Taishi Ueda in the same thread did work.